# convert pictures to pixels dataframe in R (EBImage lib)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have folder with images

```
C:/Users/admin/Downloads/mypicture
```

Here several images, I need read it.
I use `library("EBImage")`

```
x <- readImage("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/mypicture")
```

then get the error

> Error in readImage("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/mypicture") :
> Unable to determine type of C:/Users/admin/Downloads/mypicture: Filename extension missing.

How to read all pictures at once,
and then extract pixel array for each picture

```
# width and height of the original image

dim(x)[1:2]

# scale to a specific width and height

y <- resize(x, w = 200, h = 100)

# scale by 50%; the height is determined automatically so that
# the aspect ratio is preserved

y <- resize(x, dim(x)[1]/2)

# show the scaled image
```

display(y)

```
# extract the pixel array

z <- imageData(y)
```

How to do it?

here two images from my folder
[image: rabbit]

[image: horse]

I need to create pixel array

```
z <- array(y)
```

like this,
where marked name of picture kBFrf.jpg

```
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]
  [1,] 0.4676471 0.5000000 0.5382353 0.5803922 0.6107843 0.6441176 0.6715686 0.6843137 0.6901961 0.7117647 0.7303922 0.7362745
  [2,] 0.4735294 0.5078431 0.5441176 0.5745098 0.6186275 0.6392157 0.6774510 0.6882353 0.7127451 0.7245098 0.7500000 0.7764706
  [3,] 0.4735294 0.5039216 0.5470588 0.5892157 0.6186275 0.6539216 0.6764706 0.7049020 0.7225490 0.7343137 0.7637255 0.7862745
           [,13]     [,14]     [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]     [,22]     [,23]     [,24]
  [1,] 0.7686275 0.7843137 0.8000000 0.8156863 0.8450980 0.8460784 0.8519608 0.8539216 0.8529412 0.8607843 0.8647059 0.8568627
  [2,] 0.8049020 0.8274510 0.8392157 0.8745098 0.8843137 0.8892157 0.8960784 0.8882353 0.8911765 0.9009804 0.8950980 0.8872549
  [3,] 0.8058824 0.8303922 0.8558824 0.8735294 0.8784314 0.8901961 0.8911765 0.8882353 0.8794118 0.8823529 0.8803922 0.8852941
```

- 

69onL.jpg

```
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]
  [1,] 0.4676471 0.5000000 0.5382353 0.5803922 0.6107843 0.6441176 0.6715686 0.6843137 0.6901961 0.7117647 0.7303922 0.7362745
  [2,] 0.4735294 0.5078431 0.5441176 0.5745098 0.6186275 0.6392157 0.6774510 0.6882353 0.7127451 0.7245098 0.7500000 0.7764706
  [3,] 0.4735294 0.5039216 0.5470588 0.5892157 0.6186275 0.6539216 0.6764706 0.7049020 0.7225490 0.7343137 0.7637255 0.7862745
           [,13]     [,14]     [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]     [,22]     [,23]     [,24]
  [1,] 0.7686275 0.7843137 0.8000000 0.8156863 0.8450980 0.8460784 0.8519608 0.8539216 0.8529412 0.8607843 0.8647059 0.8568627
  [2,] 0.8049020 0.8274510 0.8392157 0.8745098 0.8843137 0.8892157 0.8960784 0.8882353 0.8911765 0.9009804 0.8950980 0.8872549
  [3,] 0.8058824 0.8303922 0.8558824 0.8735294 0.8784314 0.8901961 0.8911765 0.8882353 0.8794118 0.8823529 0.8803922 0.8852941
```

How to create such dataframe

result  for picture with digits

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]     [,18]     [,19]
  [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 1.0000000 1.0000000
  [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 1.0000000 1.0000000
            [,20]      [,21]       [,22]       [,23]       [,24]       [,25]       [,26]       [,27]       [,28]       [,29]
  [1,] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readImage` function takes as input a vector of file names, so in order to read all images from a directory you need to list its contents

```
library(EBImage)

# create a vector of file names
fls <- dir("./img", full.names = TRUE)

# read images
imgs <- readImage(fls, 'png')

# display images
display(imgs, method = 'raster', all = TRUE)
```

[image]

Image data is stored in an `Image` class which internally holds an `array`

```
# internal representation of images data
y <- class(imageData(imgs))

# dimensions of image stack
dim(imgs)
## [1] 825 825   4  10
```

The first two dimensions correspond to the XY dimensions, the third one holds color channels (RGBA in this case), and the last one are the individual images. In order to extract a single image, for example the second one, use

```
img <- getFrame(imgs, 2, "render")
```

If you would like to refer to images by their original names you could use  an approach similar to the following.

```
# mapping of file names to frame indices
idx <- setNames(1:length(fls), basename(fls))

getFrame(imgs, idx['sample.png'], "render")
```

Comment: i.e. all my images i have to  combine in one, like your image with digits?  The second question  imageData(imgs), i have result with only 1, i edited post to load this result. What does mean this digits. Did you get such result?

Comment: They are not combined in one. When you `display` the images, you can specify `all = T` to show each image separately but on one layout, or merge them by specifying `all = F`. When you extract image data, by `imageData(imgs)` you get `height x width x nchanels x nimages` array, which you can subset as you subset arrays (however I haven't check it).  I drawn thous digits by hand. They meant 'rabbits', from Fibonacci's point of view.

Comment: yes thank you) after  imgs <- readImage(fls, 'png')   i get big massive , how to define what relate with rabbit and what with horse

Comment: Well horses are obviously bigger than rabbits, and look different. Moreover, at the moment I am writing this, I think rabbits are already everywhere, and no horses left which makes the problem trivial. But if, while you were reading your images, you have supplied `readImage()` with the `names` parameter, which says `names = c('rabbit 1', 'rabbit 1.1', 'horse', 'rabbit 2')` etc, after converting them animals into array `y` you still would be able to subset them out of this mess with `y[ , , , 'horse']`. But as I said - I don't believe any horse could survive surrounded by rabbits, just no way.

Comment: But if, while you were reading your images, you have supplied readImage() with the names parameter, which says names = c('rabbit 1', 'rabbit 1.1', 'horse', 'rabbit 2') etc, after converting them animals into array y you still would be able to subset them out of this mess with y[ , , , 'horse']   Can you show in your answer how to do it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a possible approach to subsetting the combined image array by names.